# Chrome mysteriously adds 3px to footer width

Tags: google-chrome, css, footer

The footer at my site [Atlantic Sentinel](http://www.atlanticsentinel.com) has a width specified at 960px and a max-width also at 960px. It looks fine in IE but Chrome adds 3px to the width. Why, I can't figure it out.

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
#colophon {
clear: both;
display: table;
width: 960px;
max-width: 960px;
background: #131313;
overflow: hidden;
border-top: 3px solid #0099cc;}

#colophon .widget {
display: table-cell;
float: left;
width: 22%;
margin: 2em 0 2em 2em;
background: #000;
color: #ccc;
text-align: justify;}
```

It's not the margins on the widgets. I've tried removing one, so there's only three widgets, 22% wide, and the extra 3px is still there in Chrome.

What am I missing?

Comment: Had the same problem but now i'm using also a `min-width: 960px;`

Comment: Why do you have `display: table` on `#colophon`? If you change that to `display: block`, at least on my Chrome (latest) it works.

Comment: What happens if you remove the display: table; rule?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in webkit, to fix it just set your footer to explicitly collapse the borders you added to the top of your footer like so:

```
#colophon {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Make sure to remove the `overflow:hidden` declaration as it is not needed anymore.

EDIT. Yup, a bug. Managed to recreate it here, http://jsfiddle.net/PnYPr/ . Same problem as OP's in webkit. Will submit a bug report.

EDIT 2. [Bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75791) reported.

Comment: That almost fixes it! It seems there's now just 1px extra width. If it's just in Chrome and a Chrome bug, I can live with that though.

Comment: @user1136475 you can target webkit browsers using a media query easily, that way you can set the width of your footer to 959px until the bug is worked out. Use this to target webkit browsers (safari and chrome) `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #colophon  { width:959px  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: table;` rule. It's unnecessary, and you don't need to change it to anything else like `display: block` since that's the default and you're not overriding that in your example.

Comment: Actually, anything but table display screws up the footer layout. Don't know why, but it removes the actual footer and has the widgets floating below the content.

Comment: Looks fine to me in Firefox and Chrome without any display declaration.

Answer (score 0):

try `display:inline;` code instead of `display: table-cell;` and then see if you have achieved???

Comment: Same problem. Still an extra 1px width. That's with border collapse.